# JQuery-Bootstrap-Expanding-Vertical-Menu overlaps Bootstrap grid system

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

On implementing this [expanding left menu](http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Expanding-Sidebar-Navigation-with-jQuery-and-Bootstrap-3-Vertical-Menu.html) at Rails 4, I have an overlap problem created with the grid system.

On first image, the Home page does not have any grid system quotation (e.g col-sm-12) and displays nice.

Second image does have col-xs-12 quotation and then problem comes.

[image: menu as it should be]

[image]

Here is the css (only large screens):

```
.navbar-vertical-left {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 160px;
 overflow: hidden;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.navbar-vertical-left ul.navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar-vertical-left ul.navbar-nav:before,
.navbar-vertical-left ul.navbar-nav:after {
  display: none;
}


.navbar-vertical-left ul.navbar-nav > li {
  display: table-row;
  float: none;
}

.navbar-vertical-left ul.navbar-nav > li > a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-vertical-left ul.navbar-nav > li > a > i.fa {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

/* Colors */

.navbar-vertical-left {
  background: $green-medium;
  color: $white-letters;
}

.navbar-vertical-left ul.navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: $white-letters;
}

.navbar-vertical-left ul.navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-vertical-left ul.navbar-nav > li > a:active {
  background: $green-light;
}

.navbar-vertical-left ul.navbar-nav > li > a.selected {
  background: $green-light;
}

/* Animation */

.navbar-vertical-left {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
     -moz-transition:    -moz-transform .3s;
          transition:         transform .3s;

  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px);
     -moz-transform: translateX(-100px);
          transform: translateX(-100px);
}
.navbar-vertical-left:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
     -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
          transform: translateX(0px);
}

.navbar-vertical-left ul.navbar-nav {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
     -moz-transition:    -moz-transform .3s;
          transition:         transform .3s;

  -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
     -moz-transform: translateX(100px);
          transform: translateX(100px);
}

.navbar-vertical-left:hover ul.navbar-nav {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
     -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
          transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

And here the navbar (temporary) implementation:

```
<!-- <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(event) {
    $('a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    event.preventDefault();
  })
});
</script> when active, colors work, but clicks does not. FIX --> 
<nav class="navbar navbar-vertical-left">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><%= link_to icon('home', 'Home', class: 'fa fa-fw fa-lg'), root_path %></li>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li><%= link_to icon('user', 'User', class: 'fa fa-fw fa-lg'), current_user %></li>
  <li><%= link_to icon('users', 'Plaza', class: 'fa fa-fw fa-lg'), root_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to icon('wrench', 'Settings', class: 'fa fa-fw fa-lg'), root_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to icon('sign-out', 'Sign out', class: 'fa fa-fw fa-lg'), root_path %></li>
  <% else %>
  <li><%= link_to icon('sign-in', 'Sign in', class: 'fa fa-fw fa-lg'), root_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to icon('user-plus', 'Sign up', class: 'fa fa-fw fa-lg'), root_path %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I can guess there is 2 solutions. One is to fully overlap, other is to push. But have not clue on how

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) inside of your css? see this [picture](http://www.websiterox.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/zindex.gif) if in doubt

Comment: Thanks Tim. I was not familiar with the z-index. Just by looking the links I understood. I will answer the question with that. Thanks again.

Comment: Perfect! I am happy this solved it!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Tim Kos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4918287/tim-kos) I realize css includes z axis. Ui elements are stock from the fartest (0) to the closest in relation with the viewer (3 or n). Note it also admits negative numbers...

So, to avoid grid trouble with Bootstrap all was needed was to overlay the menu over the rest of the page by adding the last line in this snippet:

```
.navbar-vertical-left {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 130px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Thanks.